# regex not working for php form validation

Tags: php, regex

Usernames on my website should only contain A-Z,a-z,0-9. No spaces or special characters.

I have the following php code in my register form however when I input a username which contains only letters it outputs the error, any help?:

```
if (!preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/gm', $_POST["userName"])) {
    $output = json_encode(
       array(
         'type' => 'error',
         'text' => 'Your username must not contain any spaces or special characters.'
          ));
    die($output);
}
```

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do that?

Comment: <3 Regex101 https://regex101.com/r/W67Jf9/1, `^` should be outside the list

Comment: Uhhh... http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

Comment: There is no `g` modifier.

Comment: Use `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/'`

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong,Try these

```
<?php   
 if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', "name")) {
         echo "incorrect";
    }else{
      echo "correct";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is this fixing? `"name"` will always match and this does the opposite of what OP is doing

Comment: !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', "name") syntax error

Comment: @user3783243 fixes my syntax, I had ^ inside the list, and $ is the end of the string.

Comment: @AshleyNunn That's a typo, not invalid syntax. It was creating a negative character class, just remove `!` from the `preg_match` and the `g` modifier and would have worked.